# failed to createCaptureSession in image format YUV_420_888

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to get the camera preview with the recommended format YUV_420_888, 
 `map.isOutputSupportedFor(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)` returns true, and `map.getOuputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)` result contains the size 640x480, but the code still fails.

```
// We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        //mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
        ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            }
        }, null);
        //mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
```

The logcat error message:

> 09-06 14:47:06.238 17720-17783/com.example.android.camera2basic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RequestThread-0
>   Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 17720
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.util.Size.getWidth()' on a null object reference
>   at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.checkAspectRatiosMatch(RequestThreadManager.java:590)
>   at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.configureOutputs(RequestThreadManager.java:441)
>   at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.access$800(RequestThreadManager.java:61)
>   at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager$5.handleMessage(RequestThreadManager.java:658)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: This smells like a platform bug. Which device is this? Which OS build? At any rate, the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7c548a4/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/legacy/RequestThreadManager.java#437) suggests that the problem is not with your choice of `YUV_420_888` output format.

Comment: MEIZU MX3 M351, Android 5.0.1. It seems that the device doesn't support the combination of the size and the *YUV_420_888* output format. But I have tried every supported size returned by *getOuputSizes* and they all failed.

Comment: I am afraid you are out of luck.Try to run some open source camera2 example before you waste your time looking for a working combination. I won't be surprised if in the end, you'll be forced to use the old Camera API.